# SignalR - Possible Values for Transport Method for a Connection on Client

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I am just trying to find the values for the SignalR Transport method from the Client.

I believe I can get the transport method via this javascript call:

```
$.connection.hub.transport.name
```

But I would like to use the value for some other logic so I need to know the potential values. And I couldn't find that information online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sample:**

$.connection.hub.start( { transport: 'longPolling' });

Other possible transports:

- "webSockets"
- "foreverFrame"
- "serverSentEvents"
- "longPolling"

**Details:**

Please read for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#transport